# Error writing to CSV - Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fopen, fwrite

On my site users fill out a form to register, this info then gets added to a database. I'm trying to get the info to be written to a CSV file also. The code I have so far gives me this error:

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/content/m/a/t/matronryan/html/sendmail3.php on line 122

Line 122: $fp = fopen($filename, "w");

I can't work out what the problem is. Here's the code:

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$stilldonate = $_POST['stilldonate']; // not required
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$bid = $_POST['bid']; // required
$item = $_POST['item'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1']; // required
$address2 = $_POST['address2']; 
$city = $_POST['city'];
$county = $_POST['county']; // required
$postcode = $_POST['postcode']; // required
$updated = $_POST['updated']; 

include('db_functions.php');
    connect_to_db();
    $query="insert into auctionusers (firstname, lastname, address1, address2, city, county, postcode, email, phone, bid, stilldonate, item, updated) values ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$county', '$postcode', '$email_from', '$phone', '$bid', '$stilldonate', '$item', '$updated')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);


$filename == 'auctionusers.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auctionusers");

// fetch a row and write the column names out to the file
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

// remove the result pointer back to the start
mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

// and loop through the actual data
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);

}

fclose($fp);

mysql_close();


header('location: index2.php?op=Thank You&id=bid');

}
?>
```

Can Anyone see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$filename == 'auctionusers.csv';
```

To:

```
$filename = 'auctionusers.csv';
```

Double equal performs a boolean operation upon the variable. You must've added an extra equals sign by mistake.

Comment: You're a star. The amount of times I make a single character mistake and spend an hour trying to locate the problem is unbelievable. Thanks for clearing this one up for me!